Apexcharts how to call render() in Vue3
I want to call chart.render() function to check if the chart is rendered. And found the API for Javascript as follow.

But it's can not be used for Vue3.
I tried to use ref in <apexchart> template to get the chart instance and got the chartIns with updateOptions, distory ... but not render.
<template>
    <div class="chart-panel" id="chart-spark1">
        <apexchart type="line" height="400" :series="series" :options="lineConfig.chartOptions" ref="chartIns">
        </apexchart>
    </div>
</template>

onMounted(() => {
    console.log('chartIns',chartIns.value.render,chartIns.value.updateOptions)
    //chartIns undefined (H, G, ie, B) => X.value.updateOptions(H, G, ie, B)});
});

